# Loose searching approach

Tags: php, algorithm, search, search-engine, information-retrieval

I want to make a searching option for my site, and for fun I decided I should at least try to make it myself (If I fail, there's always Google Custom Search).

The problem is, I don't even know how to approach this monster! Here are the requirements:

- Not all keywords will be required in the search (Should one search for "Big happy world", it would also search for "Big world" "happy world" etc)
- Common spelling mistakes considerations (from a database, via edit difference or a predefined list of common mistakes (rather then => rather than, etc).
- Search in both content and titles of posts, with an emphesis on titles.
- Don't suck

I've searched my old pal Google for it, but the only reasonable things I found were academic level papers on the subject (English isn't my native, I'm good but not that good =( ).

**So in short:** does anyone know of a good place to start, a tutorial, an article, an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you actually want to construct a full text search engine (that's what these are typically called) or do you want recommendations to existing projects which would to the job?

Comment: I want to try and construct a text search engine (for a single site with not many posts), but existing projects will also be very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create your own search engine, [apache lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a mature open source library that can take care of a big part of the functionality for you.

Using lucene, you first index your information [using an [IndexWriter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html)]. This is done off line, to create the index.

On serach - you use an [IndexSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) to find documents that match your query.

If you want some theoretical knowledge on "how it works", you should read more on [information retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). A good place to start is stanford's [introduction to information retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookonlinereading.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

There are several options you could try:

- Apache Lucene (A PHP based implementation exists in the Zend Framework)
- ElasticSearch (provides a REST-like API on top of Lucene)
- Xapian
- Sphinx

Probably a bunch of others too.